# openSSH don't disclose reason for permission denial

Tags: ssh, vps, public-key

i have set up public key authentication on my VPS, and disabled password logins.
If someone tried to connect to my VPS, it right now says "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)".

I don't feel very comfortable with people knowing that I got public key authentication set up, I want bad guys to know as little as possible about my secret hideout.

How do I stop openSSH from telling all my secrets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it doesn't disclose. It's your ssh-client that prints which authentication methods it tried to use for authentication.

If I connect to a server, that has password authentication disabled, I still get `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).` and from using the `-v` flag of `ssh` I see that the client indeed tried to authenticate with `keyboard-interactive`.